# Convert julian date to YYYYMMDD using python datetime with regex

Tags: python, regex, datetime, julian-date

is there a way to convert using python datetime with regex a julian date into a calendar one with the following format: YYYYMMDD

the string I have is like this one

*abc_8g_1980_312.tif*

where 1980_312 are, respectively, YYYY_DDD. The desired output should be 19801107
I'm trying to use the website  https://regex101.com/

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is the wrong tool for the job when it comes to converting dates, you can still use it to extract the 'interesting' part of your string (`YYYY_DDD` from the image name), tho:

```
import re

filename = 'abc_8g_1980_312.tif'
date_str = re.search(r'\d{4}_\d+', filename).group()  # '1980_312'
```

Of course, if there are more patterns that might occur, I'd advise making the pattern more strict, for example you can put the above regex in a group and then match `\.tif$` after it to ensure it always searches for the pattern at the end of `tif` filenames. If it's always this format, you can completely forgo regex and just split / partition your string to extract the 'important' part but I'll leave that as an exercise for you ;)

Once you get the `YYYY_DDD` part from the filename, you can use [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to get to the actual date, e.g.:

```
import datetime

real_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y_%j')
# datetime.datetime(1980, 11, 7, 0, 0)
```

Finally, to get to your desired output you can use [`datetime.datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
str_date = real_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
# 19801107
```